# How to group data by date and specific time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the table:

```
select Name, TimeStamp from Goods
```

I want to group Goods by date from 9PM to 9PM
so the result should be like this:

```
Closes, Count, 2013-01-18 9PM 
Bikes, Count, 2013-01-18 9PM
```

How to do it?

I want to receive the data in 24 hours period, but each period starts from 9PM and ends on 9PM next day, but not only 1 day can be, I mean that result can be like this: 2013-01-17 9PM 3 records, 2013-01-18 9PM 5 records. It means that from 9PM to 9PM on January 17 we sold 3 goods. Let me know if information should be more detailed.

Another description:

[image]

The result should be like this:

```
Jamper1, 2013-01-17 21:00, 1
Jamper2, 2013-01-17 21:00, 1
Jamper1, 2013-01-18 21:00, 2
Jamper2, 2013-01-18 21:00, 2
```

Comment: I tried "case when end" and some other but it is not what I was needed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I've figured out how to do it:

```
select Name, count(*), DATEADD(DD, 0, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, dateadd(hour, 3, [TimeStamp])))
from Goods
group by Name, DATEADD(DD, 0, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, dateadd(hour, 3, [TimeStamp])))
```

Hope it will help for you too.

Answer (score 0):

This comes close, assuming timestamp is stored as a `datetime`.

```
select name, count(*), min(timestamp)
from goods
group by cast((timestamp + 3.0/24) as date)
```

It adds three hours to the timestamp for grouping purposes.  The third column is the minimum time stamp in the data.

If you want something more in your format . . .

```
select name, count(*), cast(cast(timestamp + 3.0/24 as date) as datetime) + 21.0/24
```

That will give you the 9pm time in the question.

Comment: I want to receive the data in 24 hours period, but each period starts from 9PM and ends on 9PM next day, but not only 1 day can be, I mean that result can be like this: 2013-01-17 9PM 3 records, 2013-01-18 9PM 5 records. It means that from 9PM to 9PM on January 17 we sold 3 goods. Let me know information should be more detailed.

Comment: @Sergey . . . My apologies, I left the `cast` out of the `group by` clause.  The `group by` moves everything ahead by 3 hours and then takes the date, for grouping purposes.  This does the grouping as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to show the total count of "Name" in the 12 hrs period. Although if you already know your time period is 9am - 9pm, why do you want to show the time?

```
select name, sum(name) as total, date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %l%p') as time
from goods where hour(timestamp) between 9 and 21
group by name
```

If this isn't what you wanted, please be more specific in your example table so we can help you.